# How to protect the content inside an app?

Tags: android, ios

I want to create an app, that after logging-in will allow offline access to all of the content (text and images).

I thought about simply saving all of the data as HTML or something similar to this as this will be the easiest way to display it later, but this will allow anyone with a bit of knowledge to extract all of the data in a matter of minutes, and spread it.

Does it make sense to store it in an encrypted way or something similar to that? How do I do this? If I simply use encryption-decryption functions then anyone who will be able to read the code will be able to access it...

The question holds true for both iOS and Android development, but I assume Android is a bigger issue in this case.

Comment: On Android, store your content in what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Ordinary users cannot access that content except via your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using [EncryptedSharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences). Example usage is

```
String masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC);

  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
      "secret_shared_prefs",
      masterKeyAlias,
      context,
      EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
      EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
  );

  // use the shared preferences and editor as you normally would
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
```

You might be able to find more examples through a search.

For more ideas on data security on Android, look [here, which shows how to read/write encrypted files](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data#read-files).